# how to insert the data in orc hive table

Tags: hive, orc

Is it possible to add data directly to an ORC hive table like `insert into table name,fields` ?

I saw many examples; in  all these examples data is loaded by selecting from another table.

Comment: Do you mean the "INSERT - VALUES" syntax, inserting 1 row at a time? Yes, it is possible but has strong pre-requisites in terms of setup, and the result is quite disiatrous in terms of performance -- as could be expected since **Hive has been designed for massive batch processing** >> kids, please use MySQL or MS Access if all you want to do is play with 3 records in a single table.

Comment: Read carefully https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions if you still persist in that abomination. God luck.